# Getting: "Error in cor(data) : 'x' must be numeric" when determining correlation between 2 variables in a data frame

Tags: r

[here's the dataframe and error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufkx6.png)

Comment: What are the result of these typeof(data$V1), typeof(data$V2)?

Comment: Integer on both. @LocoGris

Comment: Can you share the output of dput(H)?

Comment: structure(list(V1 = structure(c(7L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 3L, 
15L, 8L, 12L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 14L), .Label = c(" 0.769", " 1.432", 
" 1.944", " 10.298", " 24.566", " 34.955", " 36.016", " 39.332", 
" 44.315", " 5.177", " 5.202", " 50.808", " 53.228", " 6.861", 
" 71.674"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(13L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 12L, 14L, 5L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 2L), .Label = c(" 64.7", 
" 67.1", " 71.3", " 72.0", " 72.6", " 72.7", " 77.8", " 77.9", 
" 78.5", " 78.8", " 79.5", " 80.3", " 80.5", " 81.3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

Comment: the output is in the previous comment @LocoGris

Comment: Try this: H$V1 <- as.double(as.character(H$V1))
H$V2 <- as.double(as.character(H$V2))
cor(H)

Comment: it's still giving me the same error message @LocoGris

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are factors. Convert to numeric. It's convoluted, but convert to character first (converting from factor directly leads to weirdness).

```
library(dplyr)
H <- H %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```